# Disable /net ghosting for autofs5

Tags: arch-linux, nfs, automounting, autofs

I recently have been trying out Arch Linux. It seems that their autofs has a usability bug, although I confess that I'm new enough to Arch that I may be missing something horribly obvious.

I want autofs to automagically mount hosts under `/net` like it has always done. Traditionally it used `/etc/auto.net` to accomplish this, however it seems that they've done away with this and now you simply use the following line:

```
/net -hosts --timeout=60
```

Fine and dandy, most things seem to work. However, under Arch it seems that ghosting is enabled by default. This is a bad thing, because it uses my hosts file which only contains aliases of my local host (which is NOT running an NFS server, mind you). As a result, I get all kinds of errors about being unable to mount these hosts *every time* I run an `ls` in `/net`.

Notice: I'm not using `--ghost`, and yet it enables it by default. Arch [confirms this on their wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#NFS_Network_mounts). This is extremely annoying, how do I *disable* ghosting? Google has failed me horribly, any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/conf.d/autofs` and change or add the following

`BROWSE_MODE="no"`